Is it legal for a hospital or surgery center to discharge a patient when it is not in the patient's interest, medically?
EDIT: I removed the personal details to focus on the question. Thanks for the feedback.
Is it legal for a hospital or surgery center to discharge a patient or pressure them to leave when it is not in the patient's interest, medically?*
For example, Patient 1 is sick and the doctor wants them to stay overnight for observation, but the hospital pressures the doctor to discharge them early because they need their room/bed for Patient 2 who came to the hospital later. This is against the best medical interest of Patient 1, but overall might have the best probability of saving both lives. The doctor might also opt to send one of them to a different hospital with more room, but even this decision could be against one of their best medical interests.
I found reference to regulations that prevent hospitals from discharging patients who are not ready for discharge. Do the same regulations apply to surgery centers? Also, the regulations only seem to require a "discharge evaluation" from the provider if the patient is "likely to suffer adverse health consequences upon discharge." It doesn't appear to actually prevent discharging patients against their best interest, although I may be misinterpreting it.
https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-42/chapter-IV/subchapter-G/part-482/subpart-C/section-482.43
*This question ignores other reasons why the patient might want to stay at the healthcare facility that are not medical.

There are a lot of things wrong with this story. A nurse cannot administer opioids on their own. Your wife should have taken you to the ER. Your recollection of the events may be unreliable due to the influence of pain, anesthetics, and the opioids. Medical professions are regulated by states, not the federal government.

@littleadv, you're right my recollection could very well be unreliable. I guess my wife didn't take me to the ER because she trusted their judgement that I was safe to be released and thought that this must be normal/expected? Also, the nurse very likely did get permission from a doctor to administer the drug. That's irrelevant to the question. I'll edit the question to add a state tag. I thought this is something that would be mostly universal in the US.

If a doctor prescribed a treatment, if a doctor deemed you safe to be discharged, what is it that you're asking then? Evidently you didn't die. You "guess" your wife didn't take you to the ER, of all the people involved that the one you can actually ask. Why do you need to guess?

I wonder what the clinic would have done if your wife had said "No. He is under your care and is clearly not in a fit state to leave." Despite being accompanied by children.

@littleadv Even if a doctor did discharge me, they could be wrong and working under external pressure to free the bed for another patient. My explanation for why my wife didn't take me to the hospital is the explanation she gave me. I qualified it by saying "I guess...?" because I recognize that decision is questionable. You're arguing the premise of my personal experience when the question: 'Is it illegal to discharge someone when it's unsafe for them' stands regardless of my specific experience. Why are you being so hostile?

I'm not hostile. "unsafe" is not something easily quantified. Unsafe in what way? They didn't just dump you on the street. They made sure you're not alone, not operating any machinery, not a danger for yourself, and not in any immediate danger due to a medical condition. You feel like they did something wrong because you were sent home not in perfect health, but that's not the same as "unsafe".

@littleadv, ok then "For the sake of the question, let's assume the nurse knew sending me home was unsafe and did it anyway." I'll admit in this specific example it may have been safe to send me home. You've convinced me I don't have much of a legal argument to sue or press charges if I wanted to (which once again, I don't), but I think the general question is still relevant.

It might be possible to salvage the title question and edit away a lot of detail, because the title question is a suitable legal question. But I don't have the time to do so.

Imnotarobot, they're not robots either, meaning there is no objective, binary safe/unsafe definition.  They made a judgement call and it all worked out OK in the end, right?  Now, if there were negative consequences you could challenge their judgement in court and a jury may agree with you, otherwise you probably won't find a specific law governing their actions.  They likely operate off internal guidelines for the discharge of patients which could be subpoenaed, but otherwise aren't likely to be made public.

I'd never even heard of surgery centers before this, I had to google it. Since they're usually used for low-risk procedures with short stays, I suspect this issue is not very likely to come up.

I'm not sure what such a law would look like. Ultimately, I think pretty much everybody who goes to the hospital would be marginally better off staying under observation for another day, but at a point it's not really worth it. But how do you get a law to account for that without making it simply a matter of the doctors' professional judgment? "Likely to suffer adverse health consequences" is a decent semi-objective standard, but that still leaves a lot of room for interpretation.

In general there is much resistance to the government dictating the conditions around health care decisions made between doctors and their patients.  Any such law, (if one exists) is bound to be intentionally vague and unsatisfying towards your query.

I am not sure, but I am sure, the most basic connection of a healthy society is that no one can ever die in a curable sickness, even if s/he has not the money to cure. That we could call automatic insurance by being a homo sapiens.
